# Error when try to update:schema

Tags: php, symfony

[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]

Class 'Cunningsoft\ChatBundle\Entity\AuthorInterface' does not exist.

This error occur when i insert (new Cunningsoft\ChatBundle\CunningsoftChatBundle(),) in AppKernel.php and after implements (AuthorInterface)in my entity can't update:schema with this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LHK3.png)

```
<?php
//AppKernel.php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
            new helloBundle\helloBundle(),
            new RegBundle\RegBundle(),
            new IndexBundle\IndexBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),   
            new Cunningsoft\ChatBundle\CunningsoftChatBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\TimeBundle\KnpTimeBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'), true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

Comment: show us your entity and `AuthorInterface` class.

Comment: Does your entity implement AuthorInterface?

Answer (score 0):

you should to map the interface to the user entity

```
// app/config/config.yml
// ...
doctrine:
    orm:
        resolve_target_entities:
            Cunningsoft\ChatBundle\Entity\AuthorInterface: Acme\ProjectBundle\Entity\User
```

Comment: doctrine:
    orm:
        resolve_target_entities:
            Cunningsoft\Bundle\ChatBundle\Entity\AuthorInterface: RegBundle\Entity\Username

//or totally right there